# Allow users to download files outside webroot

Tags: php, download

Hello I am using PHP to allow users to upload files and I have them sitting in a folder outside webroot (/var/www) folder for security reasons. It is in the folder /var/uploads. A user uploads files for specific records. Once the the uploaded files are moved to the uploads folder, the address of the attachment is stored in the database. Now whenever a user checks the record, attachments for the specific record are going to be displayed for downloads.

Since they are out of the webroot, I am unable to get them downloaded as they would have a url of

> http://localhost/var/uploads/attachment.txt

Do we have a solution or should it downloadable folders be child directories of the webroot?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","id","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select * from attachments");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<a href="'.$row[2].'" target="_blank">Download</a>--'.$row[3].'<br>';
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

is the code I am using. The folder's owner is www-data:/ or the web server. So there should be no access issues.

Comment: "Now whenever a user checks the record, attachments for the specific record are going to be displayed for downloads" - Doesn't this undermine your need for security?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

- a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) pointing to `/var/uploads` (tutorial [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/19/how-to-create-symlink/))
- a Apache [`Alias` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) `Alias /uploads /var/uploads` (must be in httpd.conf)
- or a proxy PHP script that accepts a GET variable `filename=upload.jpg` and fetches the file e.g. using `fpassthru()`

the latter is the least preferable option because it is resource intensive, but sometimes it's the only alternative. It also needs proper securing to prevent an attacker from getting other files on your server through the proxy.

Comment: What is a symlink?? I am a newbie to uploads and downloads! Don't mind

Comment: @sai do you have access to your server? Root access?

Comment: Despite system overhead, the latter does have a distinct advantage. Keeping everything inside of your script gives you more control so you can edit the contents before sending them or verify user credentials before sending the file.

Comment: @Yes I do have root access to the server.

Comment: Also why would I have to put an alias for uploads?

Comment: @sai I added a Wikipedia link and tutorial link to the question. An alias would be another way to map `domain.com/uploads` to `/var/uploads`

Comment: @pekka I am working on ubuntu, and have apache2.conf file and I have added this like "Alias /uploads /var/uploads". Is this the way alias is added?

Comment: @sai if you added it in the VirtualHost directive, it should work - try it out.

Comment: @pekka I am unable to get those files when I do this "http://localhost/uploads". Am I making some mistake?

Comment: @sai impossible to tell. Probably worth a new question with more details

Answer (score 1):

You can, just have a php file that echos the contents the file to the response, and set the mime-type appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to take a load of PHP is with [`mod_xsendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) if you can install it, all the PHP process has to do is send a reply header & exit, and the webserver will take care of the rest.