# Let users download files that are not in a web directory?

Tags: php, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow users to download files outside webroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884677/allow-users-to-download-files-outside-webroot)

Hi guys I want to use php to allow users to download files from a directory on my server that is not part of my "web" files...is there a way to do this?

e.g.

my web files are in /www/bla/bla

but the files I want downloaded are in /home/bla/bla

Comment: Look up how to get apache to follow links. Or wait for someone to post an answer about that. I've done it, but don't have the config available here.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is something like this:

```
$file = '/home/bla/bla/file.ext';    

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

[readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) simply retrieves the content of the file and prints this. The rest of the code is to force the download.