# PHP, wamp, share local file, href='c:\path\file.doc',

Tags: php, wamp, share, href, local

Wampserver 2.2 
PHP

`$path` is outside the www-root.

```
$path = 'file:///c:/path/files'<br />
$file = 'file.txt'<br />

echo "< a href='$path/$file'> . $file . < /a>< br />";
```

How do I make this accessable so visitors can download `$file`? Nothing is happening when I click the link. This is a part of a small and simple document management system.

Answer (score 1):

You mix up two concepts:

- The file path **on the server** where a file is stored
- The URL for **the client** where to find that file

it is one of the more important functions of a webserver to abstract apart these two locations.

If you want to server a file from **outside** of your www-root, you need to create a helper script **inside** your www-root, that does the download. If you write this in PHP, look at the  `fpassthru()` or `readfile()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Outsiders can't access files on your computer just by providing the link to them! This would be a huge security issue!

See this answer here
[Allow users to download files outside webroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884677/allow-users-to-download-files-outside-webroot)