# Allow users to download when authorised

Tags: php, html, security, authentication, web

A quick question really. I'm creating a website that holds files, and when that user has purchased the file, the file will then download.

The only problem is, is that the directory is protected with .htaccess permissions in order to stop unauthorised downloading of files. So obviously, when a user clicks the link to download the file, they are presented with the .htaccess username password combination.

Is there a better way to manage this?

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Store your files *outside* the document root.
- Have your own custom login mechanism
- Serve the file *with* php *after* you check whether the user is logged in, either with `readfile()`, or better if it's installed or you can install it, with [`mod_xsendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) (which takes a load off PHP).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! Unfortunately GoDaddy do not allow you to place folders outside of the root, but instead they have a setting which you can use to prevent internet access to a folder (Effectively the same thing). This reply is for people in the same boat as me :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HTACCESS, put the files outside of webroot and serve them them via code.

See:

[Allow users to download files outside webroot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884677/allow-users-to-download-files-outside-webroot)