# Displaying an image in Web browser, Ubuntu

Tags: image, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04

I want to display an image on my website.

My website is located in

> /var/www/html/mywebsite

The image is located in

> /home/user/directory/image.png

I am using codeIgniter and Image src I am passing is same as above.
File/directory permissions are proper but still I am unable to display an image.

Comment: Why dont you put your images in your webserver ?

Comment: I am using unix file system for each user to view his files/directories..
So every user may have different files

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796215/an-url-to-a-windows-shared-folder Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @VishalKinjavdekar make one folder at `/var/www/html/mywebsite` with name `image` store images in that folder and try to retrieve

Comment: @Ramkee yes I want in the same way but this solution opens an image as  a file in a tab. I want to give a path to an image <img src="/home/directory/image.jpg" >
Adding a `file:// ` doesn't work here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow users to download files outside webroot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884677/allow-users-to-download-files-outside-webroot)